# How to Get Latitude & Longitude from an address php

Tags: php

I have used the autocomplete of geocode but when I am selecting from the drop down it is giving me the lat and long of the address.

I need to check when the lat and long are empty then from the posted address I must get the latitude and longitude in php.

I search this in other blogs and etc. But I couldn't get correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php

$address = 'your address here';

$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

echo "lat:".$lat."<br>"."long:".$long ; 

?>
```